# qloguniform search space setting issue in Hyperopt

Tags: python, machine-learning, hyperparameters, hyperopt

I am working on using hyperopt to tune my ML model but having troubles in using the qloguniform as the search space. I am giving the example from [official wiki](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin#13-the-trials-object) and changed the search space.

```
import pickle
import time
#utf8
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, STATUS_OK, Trials

def objective(x):
    return {
        'loss': x ** 2,
        'status': STATUS_OK,
        # -- store other results like this
        'eval_time': time.time(),
        'other_stuff': {'type': None, 'value': [0, 1, 2]},
        # -- attachments are handled differently
        'attachments':
            {'time_module': pickle.dumps(time.time)}
        }
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(objective,
    space=hp.qloguniform('x', np.log(0.001), np.log(0.1), np.log(0.001)),
    algo=tpe.suggest,
    max_evals=100,
    trials=trials)
pd.DataFrame(trials.trials)
```

But getting the following error.

> ValueError: ('negative arg to lognormal_cdf', array([-3.45387764,
>   -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764,
>          -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764,
>          -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764,
>          -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764,
>          -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764, -3.45387764]))

I have tried without log transform as below but the output values turns out to be [log transformation](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin#21-parameter-expressions) (ex-  1.017,1.0008,1.02456), which is wrong. It is consistent with the documentation.

```
hp.qloguniform('x', 0.001,0.1, 0.001)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the last argument to the `hp.qloguniform`, `q` and how `tpe.suggest` uses that.

1. First let's discuss about the `q`. According to the documentation:

   > **hp.qloguniform**(label, low, high, q)
   >
   > ```
   > round(exp(uniform(low, high)) / q) * q
   > ```
   >
   > Suitable for a discrete variable with respect to which the objective is
   >   "smooth" and gets smoother with the size of the value, but which
   >   should be bounded both above and below.

   `q` here is a `"quantizer"` which will limit the outputs from the defined space to the multiples of `q`. For example, the following is what happens inside the `qloguniform`:

   ```
   from hyperopt import pyll, hp
   n_samples = 10

   space = hp.loguniform('x', np.log(0.001), np.log(0.1))
   evaluated = [pyll.stochastic.sample(space) for _ in range(n_samples)]
   # Output: [0.04645754, 0.0083128 , 0.04931957, 0.09468335, 0.00660693,
   #          0.00282584, 0.01877195, 0.02958924, 0.00568617, 0.00102252]

   q = 0.005
   qevaluated = np.round(np.array(evaluated)/q) * q
   # Output: [0.045, 0.01 , 0.05 , 0.095, 0.005, 0.005, 0.02 , 0.03 , 0.005, 0.])
   ```

   Compare the `evaluated` and `qevaluated` here. `qevaluated` is in multiples of `q` or we say that its quantized in the "intervals" (or steps) of `q`. You can try changing the `q` value to learn more.

   The `q` you defined in the question extremely large as compared to generated sample range (`0.001 to 0.1`):

   ```
   np.log(0.001)
   # Output: -6.907755278982137
   ```

   So, the output of all of the values here will be 0.

   ```
   q = np.log(0.001)
   qevaluated = np.round(np.array(evaluated)/q) * q
   # Output: [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
   ```
2. Now coming to `tpe.suggest`(Section 4 of [this paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4443-algorithms-for-hyper-parameter-optimization.pdf)): TPE uses a tree of different estimators to optimize the search process, during which it divides the search space depending on the generator of space (in this case `qloguniform`). See [code here](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/blob/master/hyperopt/tpe.py#L526) for details. For dividing the space into multiple parts, it will use the `q`.

   But since all the points in your space will be 0.0 (as described above), this negative `q` generates invalid bounds for `lognormal_cdf` [which is not acceptable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) and hence the error.

So long story short, your usage of `q` is not proper. As you already said in the comment:-

> Also `q` value should not be used inside the log uniform/log normal random sampling according to `round(exp(uniform(low, high)) / q) * q`

so you should only supply values of `q` which are valid for your required space. So here, since you want to generate values between `0.001` and `0.1`, the `q` value should be comparable to them.

I agree that you supply `np.log(0.001)` and `np.log(0.1)` inside the `qloguniform` but that is so that the output values are between 0.001 and 0.1. So dont use `np.log` in `q`. `q` should be used according to generated values.

Comment: Thanks for your response Vivek. As you know, for hyper parameters like learning rate, range would be less than 1 hence its log range would be negative right; can you add the explanation for that too. Also q value should not be used inside the log uniform/log normal random sampling according to ound(exp(uniform(low, high)) / q) * q